# Android: BLE Custom Service UUID not finding

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I try to get the custom service UUID from BLE devices using Android phone. But Unfortunately, I am not able to get the custom service UUID from Samsung note 4, Lollipop version. But Using same code. I can get the custom service UUID from Nexus 5 , Marshmallow. I used following code.
List getServices ()

e.g . mBluetoothGatt.getServices(), getting null on the Samsung note 4, Lollipop version And Getting custom services on the Nexus 5 , Marshmallow. 
Can anyone help me out ? Thanks!.

Comment: Post your code please..

Comment: I followed the exactly this example , https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/cefd49aae65dc85161d08419494071d74ffb982f/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/src/com/example/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeService.java . And I used  public List<BluetoothGattService> getSupportedGattServices() {
        if (mBluetoothGatt == null) return null;
        return mBluetoothGatt.getServices();
    }

Comment: Did you discover the services before calling getServices?

Comment: Yes, I did. Same coding working for Nexus 5, Marshmallow , But not working on Samsung , Lollipop 5.1.1.

Comment: Do you wait for the onServicesDiscovered callback and do you also check if status == success? I never had an issue with getting the services after successfully discovering them, but I had a lot of issues discovering the services because of errors during the service-discovery

Comment: @p2pkit Yes, I checked status==success. I am getting other default Services(device information services) but I am not getting custom services UUID only.

Comment: This sounds really strange and I run out of ideas what else could be wrong. Did you try to list all services advertised by the ble device? Maybe the UUID gets converted from a 128 bit to a 16 bit one.

Comment: Did you find out the reason?